# How to specify a daemon shutdown command with upstart?

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, administration, upstart

In an upstart configuration how do I define what command should be used to shutdown a server. Lets say I have daemon that has two seperate processes.

- startup.sh  - to start the server
- shutdown.sh - to shut down the server

Suppose I have an upstart file that looks like this.

```
description "Some Example Service"
author "Me"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn

exec satrtup.sh
```

How do I tell upstart that it should called shutdown.sh when shutting down the server? How does upstart normally expect to shut down a daemon?

Answer (score 0):

Normal shutdown consists of signaling TERM then KILL 5 seconds later. Use `pre-start exec shutdown.sh` for your situation.